# binding OracleDataReader to datatable in asp.net C# and show result in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im playing with getting data out of an remote oracle and show it on a website.

I have created a class that query the database and returns type datatable

```
namespace oraclesql
{
    public class oraclesql
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        public DataTable accessdb()
        {

            string connstring = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)  (HOST=sol.it)(PORT=1521))" +
                          "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=COOKDW)));User Id=tiger;Password=temp;";
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "select jobtype from job_status";
                using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    using (OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(rdr);
                        return dt;

                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

then on my default.aspx i try to bind the result to a gridview

```
namespace Indlagte
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        protected void drpdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {


           oraclesql.oraclesql rdr = new oraclesql.oraclesql();

           dt  = rdr.accessdb();

           Gridpatients.DataSource = dt;
           Gridpatients.DataBind();


        }

    } 
}
```

My problem is that i works ok when i select only one column, but if do a multiple column query it fails.

"select jobtype from job_status" works fine
"select * from job_status" does not work

Comment: [There's no error just bad sql. After a closer look it stopped with a outofmemory stacktrace.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911740/7032856)